# Create a view on small screens when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, I have a table and page built using Bootstrap. Here is the code:

```
<div class="row my-2">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
    <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
      <h1 class="text-uppercase">Clients</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="form-control-sm bg-dark text-light border-dark me-4" type="text" id="criteria" placeholder="Rechercher" onkeyup="showCustomers();">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <table class="table table-dark table-borderless table-lines">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Login</th>
            <th scope="col">Num. Client</th>
            <th scope="col">Date inscription</th>
            <th scope="col">Dernier accès</th>
            <th scope="col">Forfait</th>
            <th scope="col">Crédit</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="result">
          <script>
          showCustomers("xxx");
          </script>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div id="customerInfos" class="collapse">
        <p>Sélectionnez un client afin d'obtenir les détails et les paramètres associés.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Here is my table loaded :

```
<tr class="clickable-row <?=$classeStatut?>" data-utiId="<?=$uti_id?>" onclick="showUtilisateur(this);">
  <td data-label="Login">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end justify-content-md-start">
      <div>
        <img class="me-2" src="<?=getPP($uti_login)?>" width="20"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="circle <?=$connectionStatus?> d-none d-md-block mt-2 me-1">
      </div>
      <div>
        <?=mhe($uti_login)?>
      </div>
      <?php if ($uti_profil==1) { ?>
        <div>
          <i class="bi bi-shield-check mx-2 text-success"></i>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td data-label="# Client"><?=mhe(POSTE_PREFIX . $uti_numposte)?></td>
  <td data-label="Inscrit"><?=mhe(makeFRDate($uti_date_inscription))?></td>
  <td data-label="Dernière co."><?=makeFRDate(mhe($uti_lastaccess))?></td>
  <td data-label="Forfait"><?=mhe($for_nom)?></td>
  <td data-label="Crédit"><span class="<?=$classCredit?>"><?=mhe($uti_credit)?> €</span></td>
</tr>
```

So when I click on a row of the table, the showUtilisateur() function will be executed and put some infos on the customerInfos div.
That works perfectly, but I want to improve the layout of the customerInfos div.
On small screens, currently I have to go to the bottom of the page to see the div
When I click on a row, I would like to open the div as a new view, and allow to return to the table view with a "back" button.
I'm not sure how to define this kind of layout.
Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: You could put your customerInfos div in a [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/).

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you'll want to separate out whatever you define as a "small screen" from larger screens, based on whatever width creates the problems for you. You'll be creating a manual breakpoint where you create a new CSS for it.

Let's say that you decide that a small screen is anything under 600px in width. At the top of your CSS page, write this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
```

Make sure to put the closing bracket at the bottom of your CSS

Next, below your closing bracket, type this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px){
```

Copy and paste everything in your CSS above inside of those brackets. Then you can start changing the pieces that you need to change. (Make sure to put the closing bracket at the bottom of the CSS.)

With the manual breakpoints, you can define new formulas to adjust the view for your smaller screens. Hope that helps!